# How to pass list of param in Get request from Talend Api tester

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension, parameters, etl, talend

I want to call a service which takes `{id}` as param. I am not sure if that service accepts `list` of `ids` as well.

If accepting then how can I pass `list` of `ids` using Talend API tester extension?

```
API URI – https://host/api/mdm/devices/{id}/apps? page={page}&pagesize={pagesize}
```

This is [service document](https://resources.workspaceone.com/view/zv5cgwjrcv972rd6fmml/en) page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot defile multiple id's in the URL, it will not allow you to get the messages. You need to loop the job to execute multiple times. Each time it executes, it should get unique id passed to the URL through context variable. Create a context file having all the URL's according to the number of id's.

If you any option to get multiple id's in the same URL, you can defile the id's in the context file and get them.

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/+{context.id}+/apps? page={page}&pagesize={pagesize}
```

But this is not the right way to get the messages